# Insert into select statement on the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I'm currently migrating data from legacy system to the current system.

I have this `INSERT` statement inside a stored procedure.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(PRIMARY_ID, SEQUENCE_ID, DESCR)
SELECT LEGACY_ID PRIMARY_ID
 , (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
    FROM TABLE_1 T1
    WHERE T1.PRIMARY_ID = L1.LEGACY_ID) SEQUENCE_ID
 , L1.DESCR
FROM LEGACY_TABLE L1;
```

However, whenever I have multiple values of `LEGACY_ID` from `LEGACY_TABLE`, the query for the `SEQUENCE_ID` doesn't increment.

Why is this so? I can't seem to find any documentation on how the `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement works behind the scenes. I am guessing that it selects all the values from the table you are selecting and then inserts them simultaneously after, that's why it doesn't increment the `COUNT(*)` value?

What other workarounds can I do? I cannot create a `SEQUENCE` because the `SEQUENCE_ID` must be based on the number of `PRIMARY_ID` that are present. They are both primary ids.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The `SELECT` will be executed `FIRST` and only then the `INSERT` happens.

A Simple PL/SQL block below, will be a simpler approach, though not efficient.

```
DECLARE
    V_SEQUENCE_ID NUMBER;
    V_COMMIT_LIMIT:= 20000;
    V_ITEM_COUNT := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN (SELECT LEGACY_ID,DESCR FROM LEGACY_TABLE)
    LOOP
        V_SEQUENCE_ID:= 0;

        SELECT COUNT(*)+1 INTO V_SEQUENCE_ID FROM TABLE_1 T1
         WHERE T1.PRIMARY_ID = REC.LEGACY_ID


        INSERT INTO TABLE_1
        (PRIMARY_ID, SEQUENCE_ID, DESCR)
        VALUES
        (REC.LEGACY_ID,V_SEQUENCE_ID,REC.DESCR);

        V_ITEM_COUNT := V_ITEM_COUNT + 1;

        IF(V_ITEM_COUNT >= V_COMMIT_LIMIT)
        THEN
             COMMIT;
             V_ITEM_COUNT := 0;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

> **EDIT: Using CTE:**

```
WITH TABLE_1_PRIM_CT(PRIMARY_ID, SEQUENCE_ID) AS
(
    SELECT L1.LEGACY_ID,COUNT(*) 
    FROM LEGACY_TABLE L1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_1 T1 
        ON(L1.LEGACY_ID = T1.PRIMARY_ID)
    GROUP BY L1.LEGACY_ID
)
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(SELECT L1.LEGACY_ID,
       CTE.SEQUENCE_ID+ (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY L1.LEGACY_ID ORDER BY null)), 
       L1.DESCR
FROM TABLE_1_PRIM_CT CTE, LEGACY_TABLE L1
WHERE L1.LEGACY_ID = CTE.PRIMARY_ID);
```

> PS: With your Millions of Rows, this is going to create a temp table
>   of same size, during execution. Do `Explain Plan` before actual execution.

Comment: Is there no other way? I need to optimize inserting into the table because I need to insert 50+ million records.

Comment: This is not  a `bad` way. But easy for you to maintain.  We can introduce `COMMIT` in batches. If you have index for `TABLE1`'s `PRIMARY ID`, this block will be performing good, with minimal resources.

Comment: I do have indexes for `TABLE1`s `PRIMARY ID`. Although, for this table, the primary keys are `PRIMARY_ID` and `SEQUENCE_ID`. Also I need to insert other fields in the `LEGACY_TABLE` into other tables like `TABLE2` and `TABLE3`.

Comment: If that is so, definitely you should go with `PL/SQL`, and commit in batches.You have exception handling, you can log it for btter debugging etc..

Comment: Actually, I am currently using `PL/SQL` for this. I already tried this approach before but my lead wants it to do this way. If I can't any workarounds, I'll suggest using this instead. I'll accept your answer for the mean time. Thanks.

Comment: @CronasDeSe added another approach with CTE and analytical ROW_NUMBER()